# How to use array to set cell content?

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview

I have an array of strings which i will use to retrieve images for my cells.
When I run the code, the images are not placed in the correct cells. How do I get them to display in the right order?

```
myArray = @[@"string1", @"string2", @"string3", nil]; //for example

[cell setImageUsingString:[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Comment: post more code from CellForRowAtindexpath
remember that tableview reuses cells

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom cell class, add an UIImageView to it and then use this code

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:(int)indexPath.row]];
```

Comment: Thank you, I've already tried this and its not working for me. I set up a setImageUsingString method in my custom cell because I need to download the image once I have a corresponding string. But the problem is My images aren't being set in the right order.

Comment: As per the comment on your question, you need to show more code, but my guess is that your image loads are completing asynchronously and you are using a variable that references the destination cell that has changed between when the download was initiated and when it completes